# configure error: cannot find ssl library (gtmess)

Tags: ssl, network-monitoring

updated

I have tried to install gtmess messenger according to their instruction but when i want to configure it the following error appears:

```
checking for SSL_library_init in -lssl... no
checking if -lssl exists in alternate location... no
configure: error: cannot find ssl library
```

I have tried the following solutions but not worked:

1.

`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

2.

```
  apt-get install apt-file

  apt-file update

  apt-file search libssl | grep libssl-dev

  ./configure --with-ssl=/usr/bin/openssl --with-ssl-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I have to add libssl wasn't exist on my system but i installed it by step 1 above and also I'm running linux(18.04) on virtual machine.

here is the source code if you want to check configure manpage:

https://github.com/geotz/gtmess

Comment: If you installed `libssl-dev` then you shouldn't need to add either `--with-ssl` or `--with-ssl-lib` (and in any case yours look incorrect). What Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: yea after i installed libssl-dev i tried ./configure by itself again but encountered same error (linux version: 18.04)

Comment: In that case I suspect it's an OpenSSL API incompatibility as described here: [libssl Initialization](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization#libssl_Initialization)

Comment: I'm not familiar with this.  how ever i searched in gtmess config.log for ssl part and i will add it as an answer here. hope you guys had time and check that out

Comment: Have you tried installing `libssl1.0-dev` instead of / as well as `libssl-dev`?

Comment: oh man, you rescue my life :) actually I'm working on my university project and my time is so limited. it is near 10 hours I'm searching for a solution. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should install build-dependencies, clone repository, compile and install your application as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential libncurses5-dev libssl1.0-dev \
libncursesw5-dev

git clone https://github.com/geotz/gtmess
cd gtmess
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

And then run the application with `gtmess`.